# Use 'predict_contrib' in LightGBM to get SHAP-values

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm, shap

In the LightGBM [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html) it is stated that one can set `predict_contrib=True` to predict the SHAP-values.

How do we extract the SHAP-values (apart from using the `shap` package)?

I have tried

```py
model = LGBM(objective="binary",is_unbalance=True,predict_contrib=True)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred_shap = opt_model.predict(X_train) #Does not get SHAP-values
```

which does not seem to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shap values the `LGBM` way with `pred_contrib=True`:

```
from lightgbm.sklearn import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X,y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
lgbm = LGBMClassifier()
lgbm.fit(X,y)
lgbm_shap = lgbm.predict(X, pred_contrib=True)
# Shape of returned LGBM shap values: 4 features x 3 classes + 3 expected values over the training dataset
print(lgbm_shap.shape)
# 0th row of LGBM shap values for 0th feature
print(lgbm_shap[0,:4])
```

Output:

```
(150, 15)
[-0.0176954   0.50644615  5.56584344  3.43032313]
```

Shap values from `shap`:

```
import shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(lgbm)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
# num of predicted classes
print(len(shap_values))
# shap values for 0th class for 0th row
print(shap_values[0][0])
```

Output:

```
3
array([-0.0176954 ,  0.50644615,  5.56584344,  3.43032313])
```

Looks the same to me.

Comment: That is odd - I just get predictions when using predict that way.

Comment: Try to copy the suggested code snippet line by line and see where/how it's different from yours

Comment: Aah.. found it! I have `predict_contrib` in my model-init and not in `predict` method

Comment: Might be why as well !

Comment: It should be `pred_contrib=True` in `.predict()` method

Comment: Yeah, I noticed from your former lead (: typical stupid  mistake !

Comment: Although the documentation states `predict_contrib` - or am I misreading that ?

Comment: I think you (and me) are reading right. I believe the documentation is misleading in this case (stale? typo in docs?). First, see in docs that `predict_contrib` should be applied in `predict` method. Second try `lgbm.predict?` and see the params it expects. Actually the best way to resolve the issues like this is to go through source code

Comment: how does `predict_contrib ` work in lightgbm?

Answer (score 4):

The confusion arises because of the duplication (inconsistent naming) of the controlling parameter in two different `lightgbm` APIs.

Each of the two major APIs uses its own spelling:

- [predict_contrib](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/search?q=predict_contrib) (C)
- [pred_contrib](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/search?q=pred_contrib) (python).

And the [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#predict_contrib) favors the C version (the python API spelling is not even considered an alias...)